# What type of View is that slim bar on the right side in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, ide

[image]

Can anyone tell me how is it called, what is its purpose and how to hide it, please?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's part of the version control system.

Clicking the little "person's head in a circle" icon should close it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got that. This is related to test coverage functionality and as you write unit/ui tests the right side with that red part appears. This has nothing to do with the vcs.